# Cannot resolve the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection

Previously I was not using an interface for my generic repository. When I extracted the interface from my generic repository, I added two constructors: a parameterless and a parameterized constructors I am getting the following error:

```
{"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = \"NascoBenefitBuilder.Controllers.ODSController\", name = \"(none)\".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, ControllerLib.Models.Generic.IGenericRepository, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:
Resolving NascoBenefitBuilder.Controllers.ODSController,(none)
Resolving parameter \"repo\" of constructor NascoBenefitBuilder.Controllers.ODSController(ControllerLib.Models.Generic.IGenericRepository repo)
Resolving ControllerLib.Models.Generic.IGenericRepository,(none)"}
```

My Controller at the beginning:

```
public class ODSController : ControllerBase
{   
    IGenericRepository _generic = new GenericRepository();
}
```

After extracting the interface and use it in controller:

```
public class ODSController : ControllerBase
{
    IGenericRepository _generic;
    public ODSController() : this(new GenericRepository())
    {
    }

    public ODSController(IGenericRepository repo)
    {
        _generic = repo;
    }
}
```

When I use parameterized constructor it is throwing error mentioned above.

Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer need the default constructor:

```
public class ODSController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository _repository;
    public ODSController(IGenericRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

And then make sure you've properly configured your Unity container:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IGenericRepository, GenericRepository>();
```

And that you are using the Unity controller factory in `Application_Start`:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(UnityControllerFactory));
```